# Jenkins pipeline environment variable in stage post section for reporting tools

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins pipeline which has matrix axis definition to run same step to multiple components to avoid copy pasta code in pipeline definition for running same steps to each component.

```
       matrix {
            axes {
                axis {
                    name 'COMPONENT'
                        values 'bacon', 'beans, 'eggs', 'salad'
                }
            }
```

I then have made stage which is runned actually quite fine. COMPONENT value can be found from env variables and can be nicely referenced to shell command with ${env.COMPONENT}. It will nicely create pylint reports with desirable names

problem is that i can not get it to work with that post section which should then archive reports.

```
               stage('PYTHON: Pylint') {
                    steps {
                        dir("plate/boiler_dev_env") {
                            sh """#!/bin/bash
                            ../tools/stack_exec.sh -T plate_${env.COMPONENT} 1 bash -c \"PYLINTHOME=. pylint --load-plugins pylint_django plate -r n \" > ../../pylint-report_${env.COMPONENT}.txt
                            """
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                           archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'pylint-report_${env.COMPONENT}.txt', fingerprint: true
                           scanForIssues tool: pyLint(pattern: 'pylint-report_${env.COMPONENT}.txt', reportEncoding: 'UTF-8', skipSymbolicLinks: true)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Is it possible get env variable from post build section? I think it should as we are under same stage. One way could be that after matrix i could run archiving in separate step and use search pattern for archiving but probably could not run it for issue scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved problem. Post has access to env variables also. I just had to use double quotes instead of single quotes. Inside single quotes everything is preserved and there is no variable expansion.

```
post {
    always {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: "pylint-report_${COMPONENT}.txt", fingerprint: true
        scanForIssues tool: pyLint(pattern: "pylint-report_${COMPONENT}.txt", reportEncoding: 'UTF-8', skipSymbolicLinks: true)
     }
}
```